# Alternative approach for eliminating $watch

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

As mentioned in the title in my angular application due to the below approach it leads to creation of many watch, i want to find some alternative methods for this.

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
    <first></first>
</div>
   var myApp = angular.module('myapp', []);

    myApp.directive('first', [
        function() {
            return {
                restrict: 'AE',
                replace: true,
                transclude: true,
                template: '<div id="first"><second id="second" param="paramData"></second></div>',
                scope: {
                },
                controller: [
                    '$scope',
                    '$element',
                    '$attrs',
                    function($scope, $element, $attrs) {

                    }
                ],
                link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl,$timeout) {
                    scope.paramData = "Test";
                    scope.updateParamData = function(){
                        scope.paramData = "TimeOut";
                    };
                    //$timeout(scope.updateParamData,5000);
                }
            };
        }
    ]);

    myApp.directive('second', [
        function() {
            return {
                restrict: 'AE',
                replace: true,
                template: '<div></div>',
                scope: {
                    param: '=param'
                },
                controller: [
                    '$scope',
                    '$element',
                    '$attrs',
                    function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
                            console.log("inside controller",$scope.param);
                    }
                ],
                link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                    console.log("inside link",scope.param);
                    scope.$watch(scope.param,function(){
                        console.log("inside watch",scope.param);
                        element.innerHTML = scope.param;
                    });
                }
            };
        }
    ]);
```

In the above example the param which is passed from first directive to the second directive is controlled by first directive so the para can change at any time so in the second directive i am using the watch to update the second directive HTML based on the param update.

So now the problem is if i used same kind of approach in my application at many places it leads to multiple watch, so i want to check is this approach is correct or is there is any other alternative approach for this.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There **must** be a $watch somewhere to detect the change in the value.

One way to reduce the number of watches is not to use two-way binding `scope: {param: "="}` in the `second` directive, and instead use one-way binding of `"&"`.

```
.directive("second", function(){
  return {
    scope: { param: "&" }, // this does not create a watch on the parent
    template: "<div>{{param()}}</div>" // {{ }} creates a watch
  }
})
```

Of course, you can also explicitly add a `$watch` in the `link`/`controller` (although in your particular example where you use `element.innerHTML`) it can easier be done with the template approach above):

```
link: function(scope, element){
   scope.$watch(function(){ return scope.param(); },
     function(newValue, oldValue){
       console.log(newValue, oldValue);
     });
}
```

So, the number of watches is 1 in each case.

Comment: @JoeEnzminger, yeah :) It is a good approach, just somewhat semantically questionable. But thanks for arguing that point then. It was a good learning.

Answer (score -2):

I see no way to improve this. Since you need to actually listen for changes for `param` I do not see a way different from watchers in this case.